# Entity Framework: PreWarm Execution Plans Caching

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, caching

I have a complex SQL query produced by LINQ To Entities.

- It takes 8s when execution plan is not cached in SQL Server.
- It takes 2s when execution plan is cached in SQL Server.

There is a way in EF or in SQL Server to prewarm execution plan caches?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the time difference is really related to execution plan caching on DB server side and not to query plan caching in EF (client side) or even to EF metadata view generation? These are three entirely different things.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You have a performance problem and address it as a performance problem, by taking measurements and investigating the bottlenecks. Follow the excellent [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) methodology. Read [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/) to understand what happens when your query executes.

You need to isolate some problems:

- is it a cold plan cache, as you state, or a cold *data* cache (more likely)?
- if is a cold plan cache, does compilation really last 6 seconds? I don't buy this.
- if is a cold data cache, why is your query issuing 6 seconds worth of IO?
- even with a warm cache, your query burns 2 seconds of execution. Why? Does it scan tables end-to-end? Are you missing an index or more? (hint: yes, you do).

Reading the Waits and Queues paper will teach you how to answer these questions.

Address the cause, not the symptom.